# R NAs introduced by coercion in string data frame problem

Tags: r, lattice, nas

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
marka <-c("Skoda","Skoda","Opel","Volkswagen","Toyota","Toyota","Ford","Dacia","Skoda","Volkswagen","Nissan","Renault","Hyundai","Fiat","Skoda","Toyota","Toyota","Volkswagen","Dacia","Opel","Kia","SEAT","Kia","Renault","Volkswagen","Toyota","Ford","Hyundai","Volvo","Toyota")
model <- c("Octavia","Fabia","Astra","Golf","Yaris","Auris","Focus","Duster","Rapid","Passat","Qashqai","Clio","Tucson","Tipo","Superb","Corolla","C-HR","Tiguan","Sandero","Corsa","Sportage","Leon","Ceed","Megane","Polo","RAV4","Fiesta","i20","XC60","Aygo")
dfall <- data.frame(marka,model)
xyplot(model~marka,data=dfall)
```

to make sth like this:
[image]

But I'm facing such error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In order(as.numeric(x)) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In diff(as.numeric(x[ord])) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In diff(as.numeric(y[ord])) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In (function (x, y, type = "p", groups = NULL, pch = if (is.null(groups)) plot.symbol$pch else superpose.symbol$pch,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
5: In (function (x, y, type = "p", groups = NULL, pch = if (is.null(groups)) plot.symbol$pch else superpose.symbol$pch,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Inspect the code of the method: `lattice:::xyplot.formula`.

Comment: That is a warning, not an error. A warning about NAs introduced by coercion may not be a problem in your case. Do you actually get the plot you want?

Comment: No, I don't have the plot. That's the thing.

Comment: You probably need your vectors to be factors, try `dfall <- data.frame(marka,model, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)` --- by default now this is `FALSE` so you can try changing to `TRUE`.

Comment: Ben's advice worked. Thank You!

Comment: Ah, of course. I am not using the latest R version so my default is `TRUE`. So I got the plot with the original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For others who would encounter the same problem:

as Ben explained in the comment, it was enough to set the parameter `stringsAsFactors` as `TRUE`, so that the vectors were factors.

```
dfall <- data.frame(marka,model, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```